# Why is my interactive view in matplotlib invisible in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: matplotlib, plot, interactive

I am experimenting with interactive plots in Matplotlib. The following code does not show me an interactive figure. Why? I have no output, just a blank white space.

```
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d

%matplotlib notebook
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')

ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')

zline = np.linspace(0, 15, 1000)
xline = np.sin(zline)
yline = np.cos(zline)
ax.plot3D(xline, yline, zline, 'gray')

zdata = 15 * np.random.randn(100)
xdata = np.sin(zdata) + 0.1 * np.random.randn(100)
ydata = np.cos(zdata) + 0.1 * np.random.randn(100)
ax.scatter3D(xdata, ydata, zdata, c=zdata, cmap='Greens');
```

Comment: I think this should work if it is the only code in your notebook with a fresh kernel. Is this the case?

Comment: Yeah, fresh kernel was the solution...thanks @ImportanceOfBeingErnest